# AWS Route 53 - Elastic Beanstalk EC2 and S3 all under the same domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have my Route 53 setup as follows

company.com A [EB Load Balancer]

www.company.com A [S3 Bucket]

S3 setup
Redirect all requests to another host name: company.com

I know I'm just not understanding something, but I can't wrap my head around having all S3 links go through company.com instead of company.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: The answer is going to depend on this question: What are you storing in S3 and how is it related to or used by the "company.com" web site... which is presumably served by an elastic beanstalk application?  So far, based on the existing question, it is impossible to guess what you are trying to accomplish.  What does "having all S3 links go through company.com" mean?

Comment: it's all the same AWS account, I'm storing files in S3 (all web pages are stored on the EC2 servers), so just media files from Django (images and videos) in a specific bucket called company.com. All of it is accessed by the EC2 instances that beanstalk creates.

Comment: Am I going to have to use CloudFront to accomplish this? Eventually all of this will be over HTTPS/SSL as well.

Comment: you should consider using cloudfront it will also help speedup your content delevery, there by making your website more responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to server assets (images, JS, css, etc) from within an S3 bucket, but using a custom DNS hostname, you can do the following:

- Create an S3 bucket matching your intended hostname: `assets.mycompany.com`
- Setup a DNS `CNAME` record for `assets.mycompany.com` in Route 53 => `assets.mycompany.com.s3.amazonaws.com`

This will allow you to load a file like `http;//assets.mycompany.com/foo.jpg`

Full documentation for S3 usage this way can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

If you need to serve S3/CloudFront content from your Apex aka "naked" domain (mycompany.com), you can configure an `ALIAS` record in Route 53 pointing at your S3 bucket or CloudFront host.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingAliasRRSets.html

Comment: So there is no way to do it without a sub domain?

Comment: Unfortunately, DNS does not allow an apex or "naked" domain like "mycompany.com" to provide a CNAME.  It has to be an A record.  This prevents using a CNAME to alias S3 content on a naked domain.

Comment: would CloudFront bridge the gap of native DNS support?